# Use Azure Data Factory to sum up dynamic fields

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a table looking like this:

```
id, stockplace, stock
1, A-100, 40
1, B-100, 10
1, C-100, 5
2, A-300, 90
```

Basically I have an item id and its stockplace and the amount. Sometimes an item can be in multiple stock places with different amounts of stock.
I want to have a final table that displays the total amount of stock for one distinct ID (combing all stock on all available stockplaces), including all the stock places aggregated where I can find that item. Like this:

```
id, stockplace, stock
1, A-100 & B-100 & C-100, 55
2, A-300, 90
```

I used a window flow to group by id and added a new window column with rowNumber(). I tried to add another column with the expression sum(stock) for a distinct id. But it doesn't work.

Any ideas or guidance?
Help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **aggregate transformation** instead of **windows transformation** to achieve your requirement.

- In aggregate transformation, add the Group by column `id` and in aggregates, the expression for `stockplace` is given as `collect(stockplace)` and the expression for `stock` is given as `sum(stock)`.
  [image]

The value of `stockplace` are aggregated and stored as an array and value of stock are added for every id.

**Output of aggregate transformation:**

[image]

- In order to convert the array values into `&` seperated string values , you can take the derived column transformation and give the expression as `dropRight(dropLeft(replace(toString(stockplace),'","',' & '),2),2)`.

This expression will convert the array values into strin and then replace the `comma(,)` with `&`. And then remove the starting and ending brackets.

[image]

**Final Output**

[image]

Comment: First of all: Wow! This worked exceptionally! Thank you Aswin! I have one last question: Sometimes I have listed a stockplace multiple times, as there are occurences with identical ID and identical stockplace but different stock. Which leads to multiple identical concatenated stockplaces. How could I remove the duplicates in the array?

Comment: Use `collectUnique` while aggregating, instead of `collect`